# Facebook oauth reply with improperly formatted URL parameter

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, oauth, authorization

I am trying to authenticate my Facebook app against a user.

My application provides the following for starting the oauth authorization process:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?state=abc&response_type=code&client_id=292634984182123&redirect_uri=http://dev.foo.com:12020/app/c-rex/authorize-facebook-action/&scope=publish_pages,email&type=user_agent

Then the browser redirects to Facebook, asks for the permissions and redirects to the given redirection URL but with improper URL parameters:

http://dev.foo.com:12020/app/c-rex/authorize-facebook-action/?#state=abc&access_token=wqeqeqBAJmOBc25oYf64IaJBO8Y7k0pOgfo3q3PzoystyqvGPFeve5F8RxZCWtAVUyZB14YaWaZC4escFL69UxcZCHZBI2riqx88rUdKFx7riLPY83D1uY1Qtf9LJfZBuC1nv7sJH1BmIOXV0ZAP94jiaXV5M5tNU99lucTAZDZD&expires_in=6078

As you can see the query string is empty and instead the query strings after the '#' as URL fragment. It looks pretty weird...The URL would be correct if it would not contain the hashmark. Since fragment is irrelevant for the server I can not pick up the fragment from the URL inside my code.

Is this a Facebook bug?

Comment: No, it is rather likely that you passed wrong parameters to begin with. For example that you have a `code` parameter already in there, makes no sense – you get a code _back_ from the login dialog after the user has authorized the app, and then your app has to exchange that code for an access token. So _starting_ the whole process with a `code` parameter already present makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: The 'code' does not make a difference. In fact with changed URL like https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?state=xxxx&redirect_uri=http://dev.foo.com:12020/app/c-rex/authorize-facebook-action/&response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxxx&scope=publish_pages,email&type=user_agent
 the problem remains

Comment: Go check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#login for the correct way to call the login dialog.

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

[Oauth Access Token] Format - The response format of https://www.facebook.com/v2.3/oauth/access_token returned when you exchange a code for an access_token now return valid JSON instead of being URL encoded. The new format of this response is {"access_token": {TOKEN}, "token_type":{TYPE}, "expires_in":{TIME}}. We made this update to be compliant with section 5.1 of RFC 6749.